# GKE: Impossible to delete a cluster

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, cluster-computing

I have a weird issue with GKE, the cluster has been created by Terraform, and I tried to make a change requiring a deletion and re-creation.
It failed at the re-creation because I was missing an API, so I added it and retry.
Thing is that I have a cluster that exists, empty but with `failed to delete cluster` message on it.

I never had this issue and I already destroyed and re-created this very resource. I tried to destroy all the resources created by terraform on this project but I still get an error "failed to delete cluster".

Also I tried to do it by hand on the UI but still get the same error.

I tried to do it using
`gcloud container clusters delete <cluster_name>` and got
"Failed to delete cluster, name: operation-xxx-xxx..." and got a link to the operation failed.

It's a JSON with a 401 code, with the following message:

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth
> 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
> See
> https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

I tried to re-auth but it doesn't help I get the same error.

I'm running out of idea, can you help me here?

Answer (score 1):

A 401 (unauthorized) suggests that you've insufficient permissions to delete the cluster.

Either get a [role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles) that permits your user account to delete clusters.

Or ask someone who has an account that has sufficient powers to delete it for you.

Or authenticate `gcloud` ([`gcloud activate-service-account`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account)) with the Service Account that you used to create the cluster (assuming it can delete clusters too) and then use `gcloud container clusters delete ...` optionally include `--account=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}` or just ensure the Service Account is `ACTIVE` with `gcloud auth list`.

Comment: I am the owner of the project, and tried to specify the `--account` but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found a proper solution, but what did work was to delete the whole project and start over.

Luckily for me it was a lab, not a production project...